# How to start hash of arrays and print out?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I want to start a hash of arrays and print out the values. I have tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    one=> [ 'a', 'b', 'c', ],
    two => [ 'd', 'e', 'f', ],
    three => [ 'g', 'h', 'i', ],
);


foreach my $number (keys %hash) {
    print "Array: $number = ";
    foreach (@{$hash{$number}}) {
        print "$_\t\n";
    }
}

Array: three = g    
h   
i   
Array: one = a  
b   
c   
Array: two = d  
e   
f
```

But i want:

```
Array1 a b c 
Array2 d e f
Array3 g h i
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you want the keywords matched with the array count words, i.e. `one` with `array1`, then you're probably going to have to hardcode a list. Hashes are unsorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %hash = (
    array1 => [ 'a', 'b', 'c', ],
    array2 => [ 'd', 'e', 'f', ],
    array3 => [ 'g', 'h', 'i', ],
);

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) { 
    print "Array: $key = ";
    foreach ( @ {$hash{$key} } ) {
        print "$_\t"; # Separate values by `tab`
    }
    print "\n"; # This newline was in the wrong loop in your code
}
```

Output:

```
Array: array1 = a   b   c   
Array: array2 = d   e   f   
Array: array3 = g   h   i
```

Comment: You should use `use warnings` instead of `-w`. The former is lexically scoped.

Comment: Sorting "one two three" alphabetically will not result in the right order.

Comment: I didn't know about -w - That's useful... How can it be lexically scoped?

Comment: But sorting array1 array2 array3 will right? There seems to be some inconsistency in the question...

Comment: I assume the OP wants a running count on the arrays, but doesn't realize hash keys are not sorted. `use warnings` can be turned off with `no warnings`. Also, I think it is better to write it out in full, as that makes it part of the code, and not the shebang.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `$number` is an element of `keys %hash`:

```
foreach my $number (keys %hash) {
```

And `keys %hash` is, sensibly enough, the keys of `%hash`: strings containing "one", "two", and "three".  If you want to use numbers as keys instead, you can:

```
my %hash = (
    1 => [ 'a', 'b', 'c', ],
    2 => [ 'd', 'e', 'f', ],
    3 => [ 'g', 'h', 'i', ],
);
```

Which will correct part of your problem.  The other part is where you insert the newline:

```
foreach (@{$hash{$number}}) {
    print "$_\t\n";
}
```

Instead:

```
foreach (@{$hash{$number}}) {
    print "\t$_";
}
print "\n";
```

Also notice I put the tab before the element.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you print a tab and a newline after each value here:

```
foreach (@{$hash{$number}}) {
    print "$_\t\n";
}
```

I guess you want to *seperate* the values by tabs, and want a newline at the *end*.

We can use the `join` function. It takes a separator and a list, then concatenates all items in the list with your separator in between:

```
 join "-", 1, 2, 3;  # "1-2-3"
```

So instead of that inner loop, you can write

```
print "Array: $number = ", join("\t", @{ $hash{$number} } ), "\n";
```

Comment: He doesn't actually want the key printed, he wants "Array#" with a running count (I am guessing)

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
my %hash = (
    Array1 => [ 'a', 'b', 'c', ],
    Array2 => [ 'd', 'e', 'f', ],
    Array3 => [ 'g', 'h', 'i', ],
);

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    my $text = join " ", @{$hash{$key}};
    print $key, " ",  $text, "\n";
}
```